# Unit Testing on Java's ListenableFuture and the addListener callback

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, mockito, future

I have a module that has a method which writes data to a Kinesis stream. We call it the Feedback stream.

i want to run a verify unit test on my analytics service's functions that are invoked on ListenableFuture's result, i have tried setting up mocks but am getting a ClassCast exception. I think I may be setting up the mocks incorrectly.

method i want to unit test:

```
public void writeData(KinesisRecord kinesisRecord, Response response) {

    FeedbackRecord feedbackRecord = new 
    FeedbackRecord(kinesisRecord.getVersion(), kinesisRecord.getNotificationId(), response.name(), 
kinesisRecord.getDestination());

    Gson g = new Gson();
    byte[] dataBytes = g.toJson(feedbackRecord).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> future = kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(streamName, kinesisRecord.getNotificationId(), ByteBuffer.wrap(dataBytes));

    future.addListener(() -> {
    try {
        UserRecordResult userRecordResult = future.get();
        analyticsService.trackSuccess(AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITE_SUCCESS, AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITEDATA_LOCATION + " " + userRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
        log.debug("Write to Kinesis Feedback successful, record sequence number: " + userRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        analyticsService.trackError(AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITE_ERROR, AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITEDATA_LOCATION);
        log.error("Feedback Kinesis Write failed: " + e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        analyticsService.trackError(AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITE_ERROR, AnalyticsConstants.FeedbackProducer.WRITEDATA_LOCATION);
        log.error("Feedback Kinesis Write failed: " + e);
    }
}, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

}
unit test attempt:

```
@Test
public void addUserRecordFutureTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> responseFuture = mock(ListenableFuture.class);

    Attempt attempt = new Attempt(1, 2, "AttemptError", "5xx", true);
    List<Attempt> attempts = new ArrayList<>();
    attempts.add(attempt);
    UserRecordResult mockUserRecordResult = mock(UserRecordResult.class);

    when(kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(responseFuture);
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        ListenableFutureCallback listenableFutureCallback = invocation.getArgument(0);
        listenableFutureCallback.onSuccess(mockUserRecordResult);
    // do asserts here
        return null;
    }).when(responseFuture).addListener(any(), any());

    feedbackProducer.writeData(mockRecord, FeedbackProducer.Response.invalid_channel);
}
```

STACK TRACE:

[image]

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. I don't see an explicit cast here (?).

Comment: @second neither do i ... but i just added the trace

Comment: Seems the problem is related to `invocation.getArgument(0)`. Maybe transforming that part into a non lambda expression might be helpful. Try to figure out where the first parameter of `addListener` is coming from.